# Formatting custom taxonomy terms based on term meta (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, metadata, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to prepare a list of jobs (from my custom taxonomy JOBS), which are colored differently according to their meta term (wpcf-risk). I have made the code below. But this is only showing jobs which have a wpcf-risk value assigned. There could be jobs which are not yet evaluated for risk, and they will have no wpcf-risk value. Such jobs are not showing up in the below code.  Any suggestions how to display those taxonomy terms?

```
$terms= wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'jobs' );
$colored = '#999999';
foreach($terms as $row){
    $term_id = $row->term_id;
    $taxonomy = $row->taxonomy; 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_termmeta WHERE meta_key = 'wpcf-risk' and term_id = $term_id";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
  foreach($results as $result)
    {    
    switch ($result->meta_value) {
    case "Negligible Risk":
        $colored = '#99cc00';
        break;
    case "High Risk":
       $colored = '#ff0000';
        break;
    case "Medium Risk":
       $colored = '#ff9900';
        break;
    case "Low Risk":
       $colored = '#ffcc00';
        break;
    default:
       $colored = '#999999';

}echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($row->slug, 'jobs').'">
             <span style="color: '.$colored .'; font-weight:bold;">'. $row->name.'</span></a>,';     
} 
}
```